# Mocking External Dependency object created inside a function without dependency injection in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock, catch2, fakeit

I am trying to write unit tests in C++ and am facing an issue with creating mock objects for an external dependency using Fakeit. So we have a class similar to the following:

```cpp
class A 
{
    int test_method()
    {
        B obj;
        return obj.sendInt()
    }
};

class B
{
    int sendInt()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};
```

Now let's say I want to write a unit test for `test_method()` of class `A`. When we call `obj.sendInt()` I want to mock it and return a different value. I tried using fakeit but was not able to arrive at a solution.

I know this will be solved if we try to do a dependency injection of `B` via constructor or in setter methods, but I don't want to do it as it would take some refactoring in existing consumers of `A`.

For a similar scenario in Java, I would use PowerMockito and achieve the same using `PowerMockito.whenNew`

```java
B mock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mock);
Mockito.when(mock.test()).thenReturn(2);
A obj=new A();
assertEquals(obj.test(), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use dependency injection. I don't think there's anything similar to `PowerMockito` for C++ (e.g. it's impossible to mock static methods/functions in a similar manner as `PowerMockito` allows for java).

If the issue is only with the dependency injection via ctor or setter methods, consider using [hi-perf dependency injection](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods), i.e. inject mock using templates.

If the `class A` cannot be modified at all but you own the `class B`, consider moving `class B` to a separate static library: one for production (say, `libBprod`) and one for testing (`libBtest`). In production you can link against the `libBprod` and in tests against `libBtest`. In `libBtest`, you can make `class B` a singleton under the hood. This is quite a lot of work though.

If both `class A` and `class B` cannot be modified, then I'm out of ideas - you need to refactor some part of the code somehow.

Comment: Thanks Quarra. I know this can be solved with templates , but I wanted avoid any way of DI as I dont want to change in the consumers. One way i solved is, move the code which initializes B and invokes its method to a private method and mock this private method using gmock.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code which initializes B and invokes its method to a private method and mocked this private method using gmock

```
class A 
{

int test_method()
{
return getBValue();
}
int getBValue()
{
B obj;
return obj.sendInt()
}

}
```

My Test Method looks like,

```
Class MockA :: A
{
public:
MOCK_METHOD(int,getBValue,(),override);

}

TEST_CASE("Test1")
{
MockA mock;
ON_CALL(mock, getBValue()).WillByDefault(Return(10));
REQUIRE(mock.test_method()==10);
}
```

Comment: You need to add `virtual` to `getBValue`.